# How to select and insert data into a hive table with php

Tags: php, database, hadoop, hive

I want to know if you can select and insert data into a hadoop hive table using a web application? (like you would with PHP for MySql).

If so then how?

If not then how could/would you go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Hive gives you the option to create clients written in differents programming languages through Hive Thrift Service.

Please check the [HiveServer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer) documentation and I think would be a good idea read about Apache Thrift to understand in a better way how Hive Thrift works.

Finally, [here](http://nousefor.net/55/2011/12/php/hbase-and-hive-thrift-php-client/) explains how to build a simple client with Php.